# About amicable numbers

Tags: number-theory

My question might seem wrong but I will explain it now:

We will define $\phi(a)$ as the sum of divisors of $a$ except $a$.

A pair $(a,b)$ is an amicable pair $\iff ((\phi(a) = b)  \land  (\phi(b) = a)) \land (a \neq b)$

Obviously if $(a,b)$ is an amicable pair $(b,a)$ is also an amicable pair. So, we will say $a$ is an amicable number $\iff$ There exist an $b$, such that $(a,b)$ is an amicable pair and $b < a$. Also we will say $a$ is a perfect number $\iff$ $\phi(a) = a$.

So my question is if we pick an arbitrary number, is it more likely an amicable number or perfect number? This question might be wrong because they might be finite but my question is simple: "Are there more amicable numbers than perfect numbers?"

I check with computer and believed that it is more likely an amicable number.

Let's formalize this as follows:  Let $P(n)$ be the number of perfect numbers $\leq n$, and let $A(n)$ be the number of amicable numbers less than $n$.  Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{P(n)}{A(n)}$ exist, and if so what is its value?

Comment: You should specify the probability distribution for "pick an arbitrary number".

Comment: Yes, I think so but I think someone might help me about that because my questions main point is obvious I guess.

Comment: Under most reasonable definitions of "pick an arbitrary number", the set of both amicable and perfect numbers will have measure $0$.  I'd recommend asking for $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{P(n)}{A(n)}$, where $P(n)$ is the number of perfect numbers $\leq n$ and $A(n)$ is the number of amicable numbers $\leq n$.  I'd guess the value is either $0$ or $\infty$.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the density of both perfect and amicable numbers ends up to be $0$.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't we approach that in a more comparing way? I mean, I want to compare amicable numbers and perfect numbers.

Comment: @MartianInvader: If you edit my question I will really appreciate.

Comment: @Dahlersit I've edited your question to include the formalization I suggested.

Comment: @azimut It's certainly the case that the density of even perfect numbers is 0, and I wouldn't be surprised if we know enough about odd perfect numbers to say the same about them.

Comment: No one knows (a) whether there are infinitely many perfect numbers, or (b) whether there are infinitely many amicable numbers.  If only (a) is true, your ratio diverges to $+\infty$; if only (b) is true, your ratio converges to $0$.  I suspect that not only is your ratio unknown, but that no one will be able to prove any bound on it or whether it exists.

Answer (score -1):

I got the limits that I'm basing this on mainly from Wikipedia and WolframAlpha, so feel free to correct if something's wrong.

According to Wikipedia, $P(n)<c\sqrt n$, where c is a constant. I assume that this is a rough asymptotic limit, correct me if I'm wrong. It also says that $A(n)<ne^{-{\ln(n)}^{1/3}}$, so $\frac {P(n)}{A(n)}\sim\frac {c\sqrt n}{ne^{-{\ln(n)}^{1/3}}}$. The limit is easier to evaluate after taking the logarithm, so we have $\ln ({\frac {P(n)}{A(n)}})\sim\ln(n)^{1/3}-\frac{\ln(n)}2+\ln(c)$, so the limit is $-\infty$, since the $-\ln(n)\over 2$ dominates the function as n approaches $\infty$. To convert this back into its original form, we take $e^{-\infty}=0$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{P(n)}{A(n)}=0.$

Comment: Your asymptotic estimate doesn't work - you only have _bounds_, not actual values - and only upper bounds, at that - so you can't divide out to get an estimate.  (For instance, if $a\lt 1$ and $b\lt 3$, you can't say anything about the relation between $\frac ab$ and $\frac13$.)

Comment: That's what I meant about assuming that it was a rough asymptotic limit; given two upper bounds which increase at different rates, it seems reasonable to assume that the values themselves also increase at different rates. Nonetheless, you're right; this doesn't actually prove the limit, only gives an indication.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I misinterpreted the description of "amicable numbers" so my soft answer below is for the question of the relationship between numbers where $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$ to the perfect numbers.

This is a soft answer, but I'll express my thoughts here (slightly too long for a comment):

1) Every prime number (except 2) fits the above definition, since $\phi (p) = 1$ for $p$ = prime #. There are more numbers that fit this pattern ($25$, for example, $\phi(25) = 6 = \phi(6)$).

2) We know that the even perfect numbers have a 1-1 relationship with the Mersenne primes (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_numbers) page for perfect numbers).

3) We don't know if there are any odd perfect numbers, but it does seem like if any do exist, there are many fewer of them than even perfect numbers.

4) So we may be able to limit the ratio of perfect numbers to numbers where $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$ by the ratio of Mersenne primes to primes overall. This ratio is another unknown, but empirical evidence suggests it's very small.

Again, a soft answer, but I enjoyed thinking about it.

Comment: Trivially there are fewer Mersenne primes than there are powers of 2, and the density of powers of 2 itself is exponentially small, so the density of Mersenne primes must be exponentially small (i.e., there can't be more than $O(\log n)$ Mersenne primes less than $n$).  But remarkably, I can't actually find anything that implies that odd perfect numbers couldn't have asymptotic density *much* greater than even perfect numbers - even though the empirical evidence is compelling, it's even possible that there are only finitely many *even* perfect numbers, but infinitely many odd ones!

Comment: You're confusing the definition of an amicable pair (Duncan, not Steven). Two numbers are an amicable pair $(a,b)$ iff $\phi (a) =b$ and $\phi (b)=a$, not $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$. Therefore not only are the primes not all amicable, but none are, since $\phi(1)=0$.

Comment: Ah, @Laertes that is indeed a big misreading on my part. Ignore everything above!